# Read Datagridview's templatefield value to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which i have a textbox in template field which is like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>Close</HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtClose" runat="server" Width="90px" Text='<%# Eval("Open") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
           <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
           </asp:TemplateField>
```

When am trying to convert the entire grid values to string using

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                str = str + "," + Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
            }
            str = str + "|";
        }
```

The template field values are coming up as empty strings

any ideas how to retrieve them??

Answer (score 1):

You have asp.net server controls in cell and you have to find them first to get their values. You can use [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to call on `Row` or `Cell` object to get the `textBox` in it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     TextBox txtClose = (TextBox)dgv.Rows[i].FindControl("txtClose");
     str = str + "," + Convert.ToString(txtClose.Text);
     //Find and add more template fields here.  
     str = str + "|";
}
```